# Determining the value of A given $Z_4=Z_8\oplus Z_2/A$

Tags: finite-groups, tensors, quotient-spaces

Let Z define the integers and $Z_a$ define the integer group modulo a. I want to determine what A is.

Given $Z_4\cong Z_8\oplus Z_2/A$, where $A\subset Z_8\oplus Z_2$,
am I able to just say that given $H=\{z_0, z_4\} \subset Z_8\oplus Z_2$ where $z_0=id$ and $(z_4)^2=id$, $A\cong H \oplus Z_2$? Im am doing this  just by observation so I am a bit sceptical. Are there cases where this isnt true?

i.e. If $Z_4\cong Z_8\oplus Z_2/A$ but A is defined differently to how I did it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the notation is a bit dangerous,  since you seem to be conflating $=$ with $\cong$.   Other than that,   we know that any subgroup of $Z_8\oplus Z_2$ must be of the form $B\oplus C$,  where $B\le Z_8$ and $C\le Z_2$.  So for $C$ our only choices are the trivial group and the whole group.  Also note that $|Z_4|=4$,$|Z_8\oplus Z_2|=16$,  hence $|A|=|B||C|=4$.  So,  if $|C|=1$, we have $|B|=4$, and the only subgroup of order $4$ of $Z_8$  is the one generated by the generator squared....then we would have $Z_8\oplus Z_2/A\cong Z_2 \oplus Z_2$ which is false, hence $|C|=2=Z_2$.   Then $|B|=2$, which is the only subgroup that you identified.

In other words,  your $A$ is correct and unique

Comment: Very nice! For the more general case, could there be more than one A (which are not isomorphic to each other) that satisfies a given equation X$\cong$Y/A, where X and Y are supposedly known groups?

Comment: I'm not sure that'd be true in the more general case or not.  It certainly would be true for the direct sum of cyclic groups.   By the way, welcome to stack exchange, if this answer was useful to you, you should hit the up-arrow,  if it solved your problem, you should click the check to accept it :)